# Issue with a request to Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I got a problem that I don't understand. The script was working and suddenly it say that the request is undefined.

Here is the script:

```
    function insertEvents(){

     var event = {
      "summary": userEmail ,
      "location": '4 rue mogador Trouville sur mere',
      "description": 'Test de lgtrouville.com',
      "end": [
       {"dateTime": "2018-05-28T10:00:00+02:00"},
       {"timeZone": "Europe/Paris"} 
      ],
      "start": [
       {"dateTime": "2018-05-25T10:00:00+02:00"},
       {"timeZone": "Europe/Paris"} 
      ],
      "attendees": [
       {"email": "lpage@example.com"},
       {"email": "sbrin@example.com"}
      ],
      "reminders": {
       "useDefault": false,
       "overrides": [
        {"method": "email", "minutes": 24 * 60},
        {"method": "popup", "minutes": 10}
       ]
      }
     };

    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
    'calendarId': userEmail ,
    'resource': event
    });

    request.execute(function(event) {
    appendPre('Event created: ' + event.htmlLink);
    });       
 }
```

The output said that `event.htmlLink` is `undefined`. I might have an error in the syntax of `var event`?

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty much taken directly from [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert). My first guess would be to change `request.execute(function(event) {` to `request.execute(function(response) {`, then change `event.htmlLink` to `response.htmlLink`

Comment: As another note, you might have lost authentication if it had been working for a time.

Comment: Thanks it did work! ....... oops it did work during 15 min then ....again the same output : "undefined". Maybe the API do that! because i request it a lot doing test whileI am developping, don't you think?

Comment: Solution: There is no problem at all in this code, it was simply that to many requests as been done to this API!